# Make ASP.NET Core server (Kestrel) case sensitive on Windows

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server, kestrel

ASP.NET Core apps running in Linux containers use a case sensitive file system, which means that the CSS and JS file references must be case-correct.

However, Windows file system is not case sensitive. Therefore during development you can have CSS and JS files referenced with incorrect casing, and yet they work fine. So you won't know during development on Windows, that your app is going to break when going live on Linux servers.

Is there anyway to **make Kestrel on Windows case sensitive**, so that we can have consistent behaviour and find the reference bugs before going live?

Comment: To clarify, Kestrel is not relevant, it's the PhysicalFileProvider and StaticFiles components that do this matching for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I fixed that using a middleware in ASP.NET Core.
Instead of the standard `app.UseStaticFiles()` I used:

```
 if (env.IsDevelopment()) app.UseStaticFilesCaseSensitive();
 else app.UseStaticFiles();
```

And defined that method as:

```
/// <summary>
/// Enforces case-correct requests on Windows to make it compatible with Linux.
/// </summary>
public static IApplicationBuilder UseStaticFilesCaseSensitive(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    var fileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
    {
        OnPrepareResponse = x =>
        {
            if (!x.File.PhysicalPath.AsFile().Exists()) return;
            var requested = x.Context.Request.Path.Value;
            if (requested.IsEmpty()) return;

            var onDisk = x.File.PhysicalPath.AsFile().GetExactFullName().Replace("\\", "/");
            if (!onDisk.EndsWith(requested))
            {
                throw new Exception("The requested file has incorrect casing and will fail on Linux servers." +
                    Environment.NewLine + "Requested:" + requested + Environment.NewLine +
                    "On disk: " + onDisk.Right(requested.Length));
            }
        }
    };

    return app.UseStaticFiles(fileOptions);
}
```

Which also uses:

```
public static string GetExactFullName(this FileSystemInfo @this)
{
    var path = @this.FullName;
    if (!File.Exists(path) && !Directory.Exists(path)) return path;

    var asDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    var parent = asDirectory.Parent;

    if (parent == null) // Drive:
        return asDirectory.Name.ToUpper();

    return Path.Combine(parent.GetExactFullName(), parent.GetFileSystemInfos(asDirectory.Name)[0].Name);
}
```

Comment: You could also do this at a lower layer with a custom IFileProvider.

Comment: Thanks Tracher. Do you by any chance have the implementation?

Comment: @Paymon see answer below

Answer (score 6):

Based on @Tratcher proposal and [this](http://hugoware.net/blog/ignoring-case-with-mono-mvc) blog post, here is a solution to have case aware physical file provider where you can choose to force case sensitivity or allow any casing regardless of OS.

```
public class CaseAwarePhysicalFileProvider : IFileProvider
{
    private readonly PhysicalFileProvider _provider;
    //holds all of the actual paths to the required files
    private static Dictionary<string, string> _paths;

    public bool CaseSensitive { get; set; } = false;

    public CaseAwarePhysicalFileProvider(string root)
    {
        _provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(root);
        _paths = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public CaseAwarePhysicalFileProvider(string root, ExclusionFilters filters)
    {
        _provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(root, filters);
        _paths = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public IFileInfo GetFileInfo(string subpath)
    {
        var actualPath = GetActualFilePath(subpath);
        if(CaseSensitive && actualPath != subpath) return new NotFoundFileInfo(subpath);
        return _provider.GetFileInfo(actualPath);
    }

    public IDirectoryContents GetDirectoryContents(string subpath)
    {
        var actualPath = GetActualFilePath(subpath);
        if(CaseSensitive && actualPath != subpath) return NotFoundDirectoryContents.Singleton;
        return _provider.GetDirectoryContents(actualPath);
    }

    public IChangeToken Watch(string filter) => _provider.Watch(filter);

    // Determines (and caches) the actual path for a file
    private string GetActualFilePath(string path)
    {
        // Check if this has already been matched before
        if (_paths.ContainsKey(path)) return _paths[path];

        // Break apart the path and get the root folder to work from
        var currPath = _provider.Root;
        var segments = path.Split(new [] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        // Start stepping up the folders to replace with the correct cased folder name
        for (var i = 0; i < segments.Length; i++)
        {
            var part = segments[i];
            var last = i == segments.Length - 1;

            // Ignore the root
            if (part.Equals("~")) continue;

            // Process the file name if this is the last segment
            part = last ? GetFileName(part, currPath) : GetDirectoryName(part, currPath);

            // If no matches were found, just return the original string
            if (part == null) return path;

            // Update the actualPath with the correct name casing
            currPath = Path.Combine(currPath, part);
            segments[i] = part;
        }

        // Save this path for later use
        var actualPath = string.Join(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, segments);
        _paths.Add(path, actualPath);
        return actualPath;
    }

    // Searches for a matching file name in the current directory regardless of case
    private static string GetFileName(string part, string folder) =>
        new DirectoryInfo(folder).GetFiles().FirstOrDefault(file => file.Name.Equals(part, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))?.Name;

    // Searches for a matching folder in the current directory regardless of case
    private static string GetDirectoryName(string part, string folder) =>
        new DirectoryInfo(folder).GetDirectories().FirstOrDefault(dir => dir.Name.Equals(part, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))?.Name;
}
```

Then in Startup class, make sure you register a provider for content and web root as follow:

```
        _environment.ContentRootFileProvider = new CaseAwarePhysicalFileProvider(_environment.ContentRootPath);
        _environment.WebRootFileProvider = new CaseAwarePhysicalFileProvider(_environment.WebRootPath);
```

Comment: I'm using net core 6 and got error `System.ArgumentException: 'The path must be absolute. (Parameter 'root')'
` from this code `_provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(root);`

Answer (score 0):

It was possible in [Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/266110/how-do-you-make-windows-7-fully-case-sensitive-with-respect-to-the-filesystem) but not [windows 10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/windows-10-case-sensitive-file-names/62c70981-00ed-454d-8ea3-ddf629547333?auth=1) and as far as I can tell, it's also not possible on Windows Server at all.

I can only talk about the OS because the Kestrel documentation says:

> The URLs for content exposed with `UseDirectoryBrowser` and `UseStaticFiles` are subject to the case sensitivity and character restrictions of the underlying file system. For example, Windows is case insensitive—macOS and Linux aren't.

I'd recommend a convention for all filenames ("all lowercase" usually works best). And to check for inconsistencies, you can run a simple PowerShell script that uses regular expressions to check for wrong casing. And that script can be put on a schedule for convenience.

Comment: We already do have standards to always use lower-case, but it's easy to make mistakes and ignore that rule.